# How to set a custom time for the start of a day in python?

Tags: python, datetime, pysimplegui

I want the day to start at 06:30 and end at 15:00. I'm using this for business days instead of full 24 hour days.

I'm using this to calculate how much time was taken to do a job. 30 minutes subtracted for lunch if the end time occurs after 11:30.

Or if someone who is better at math than me can figure out how to calculate that with what is already written

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime as dt


startRow = sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startMonth'), sg.T('/'), sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startDay'),  sg.Text(' '*5), sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startHour'), sg.T(':'), sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startMinute')

endRow = sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='endMonth') , sg.T('/'), sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='endDay'),sg.Text(' '*5), sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='endHour'), sg.T(':'), sg.InputText('', size=(2,1), key='endMinute')



layout = [
  [sg.T('Enter the times you wish to calculate')],
  [sg.T('(Uses 24-Hour format)')],
  [sg.T('Enter a start Date and Time', size=(30,1))], 
  [startRow],
  [sg.T('Enter an end Date and Time', size=(30,1))],
  [endRow],
  [sg.Text(' '*50, key='result')],
  [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.CButton('Cancel')]
]

window = sg.Window('Process Time Calculator', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    startMonth = int(values['startMonth'])
    startDay = int(values['startDay'])
    startHour = int(values['startHour'])
    startMinute = int(values['startMinute'])
    yr = dt.datetime.now()
    endMonth = int(values['endMonth'])
    endDay = int(values['endDay'])
    endHour = int(values['endHour'])
    endMinute = int(values['endMinute'])
    
    startTime = dt.timedelta(hours=startHour, minutes=startMinute)
    endTime = dt.timedelta(hours=endHour, minutes=endMinute)
    startDate = dt.datetime(year=yr.year, month=startMonth, day=startDay)
    endDate = dt.datetime(year=yr.year, month=endMonth, day=endDay)
    startDateTime = dt.datetime(year=yr.year, month=startMonth, day=startDay) + startTime
    endDateTime = dt.datetime(year=yr.year, month=endMonth, day=endDay) + endTime
    timeCalc = endDateTime - startDateTime
    result = timeCalc.total_seconds() 
    finalResult = float(result / 3600.0)
    if startDate != endDate:
      if finalResult >= 24:
        finalResult = finalResult - 16.5
        
        
    elif startDate == endDate and endTime > dt.datetime(hour=11, minute=30):
      finalResult = finalResult - .5
      
    
    print("Final Result: " + str(finalResult) + "\nDone.")
    print('Start date: ' + str(startDateTime))
    print('End date: ' + str(endDateTime))
    window['result'].update(finalResult)
    window.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a long time of trying to write the math out to make it make sense to me. I finally got it to where it works now. A calculator for over 1 day, over 24 hours, and over 48 hours like a weekend.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()

startRow = sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startMonth'), sg.T('/'),                                 sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startDay'), sg.Text(' '*5),                              sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startHour'), sg.T(':'),                                  sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='startMinute')

endRow =   sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='endMonth') , sg.T('/'),                                  sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='endDay'),sg.Text(' '*5),                                 sg.InputText('', size=(3,1), key='endHour'), sg.T(':'),                                    sg.InputText('', size=(2,1), key='endMinute')

layout = [
  [sg.T('Enter the times you wish to calculate')],
  [sg.T('(Uses 24-Hour format)')],
  [sg.T('Enter a start Date and Time', size=(30,1))], 
  [startRow],
  [sg.T('Enter an end Date and Time', size=(30,1))],
  [endRow],
  [sg.Text(' '*50, key='result')],
  [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.CButton('Cancel')]
]

window = sg.Window('Process Time Calculator', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

    now = dt.datetime.now()

    #Start Date Values
    startMonth = int(values['startMonth'])
    startDay = int(values['startDay'])
    startHour = int(values['startHour'])
    startMinute = int(values['startMinute'])
    startTime = dt.timedelta(hours=startHour, minutes=startMinute)
    startDate = dt.datetime(year=now.year, month=startMonth, day=startDay)
    startDateTime = dt.datetime(year=now.year, month=startMonth, day=startDay) + startTime

    #End Date Values
    endMonth = int(values['endMonth'])
    endDay = int(values['endDay'])
    endHour = int(values['endHour'])
    endMinute = int(values['endMinute'])
    endTime = dt.timedelta(hours=endHour, minutes=endMinute)
    endDate = dt.datetime(year=now.year, month=endMonth, day=endDay)
    endDateTime = dt.datetime(year=now.year, month=endMonth, day=endDay) + endTime

    #The difference in time between the entered dates and times
    timeCalc = endDateTime - startDateTime

    #Convert the difference in time to seconds.
    result = timeCalc.total_seconds() 
    
    #Divide by the amount of seconds in an hour.
    finalResult = float(result / 3600.0)

    if startDate != endDate:
      if finalResult > 48:
        if endHour > 12 or ( endHour >= 11 and endMinute >= 30 ):
          finalResult -= 0.5
        finalResult -= 64
        #This is for time over a 2 day weekend, no lunch on weekends so the day is 24 hours not 23.5. 24 + 24 + 15.5 (-.5 for lunch) The third level if statement accounts for the following monday's lunch break.
        
      elif finalResult >= 24:
        if endHour > 12 or ( endHour >= 11 and endMinute >= 30 ):
          finalResult -= 0.5
        finalResult -= 16
        # 1500 to 06:30 is 15.5 hours with a 30 minute lunch is 16 hours.
        
    elif startDate == endDate and endHour > 12 or ( endHour >= 11 and endMinute >= 30 ):
      finalResult -= 0.5

    print(f'Final Result: {finalResult} \nDone')
    print(f'Start date:  {startDateTime} ' )
    print(f'End date: {endDateTime}')
    window['result'].update(finalResult)
    window.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you're going for.  Didn't try the "next day" thing out, so you'll have to test it few times & let us know if it still needs tweaking.  But either way, this should get'cha in the right direction.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime as dt

##  pip3 install pysimplegui
##  print( help( sg ) )  ##  was looking for a way to increase fontsize...

now = dt.datetime.now()

startRow = sg.InputText( now.month,  size=( 3, 1 ), key='startMonth' ), \
    sg.T( '/' ),        sg.InputText( now.day,  size=( 3, 1 ),  key='startDay' ), \
    sg.Text( 'Start' ), sg.InputText( '6',  size=( 3, 1 ),  key='startHour' ), \
    sg.T( ':' ),        sg.InputText( '30',  size=( 3, 1 ),  key='startMinute' )

endRow = sg.InputText( now.month,  size=( 3, 1 ),  key='endMonth' ), \
    sg.T( '/' ),        sg.InputText( now.day,  size=( 3, 1 ),  key='endDay' ), \
    sg.Text( ' End ' ), sg.InputText( '15',  size=( 3, 1 ),  key='endHour' ), \
    sg.T( ':' ),        sg.InputText( '00',  size=( 2, 1 ),  key='endMinute' )

layout = [
    [  sg.T( 'Enter the times you wish to calculate' )  ],
    [  sg.T( '( Uses 24-Hour format )' )  ],
    [  startRow  ],
    [  sg.T( 'MM  /  DD   ~ ~ ~ ~   HH  :  mm ',  size=( 30, 1 )  )  ],
    [  endRow  ],
    [  sg.Text( ' ' *50,  key='result' )  ],
    [  sg.Button( 'Submit' ),  sg.CButton( 'Cancel' )  ]
]

window = sg.Window( 'Process Time Calculator',  layout )

while True:
    event,  values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  break  ##  if user closes window or clicks cancel

    startMonth = int( values[ 'startMonth' ] )
    startDay = int( values[ 'startDay' ] )
    startHour = int( values[ 'startHour' ] )
    startMinute = int( values[ 'startMinute' ] )

    now = dt.datetime.now()

    endMonth = int( values[ 'endMonth' ] )
    endDay = int( values[ 'endDay' ] )
    endHour = int( values[ 'endHour' ] )
    endMinute = int( values[ 'endMinute' ] )
    
    startTime = dt.timedelta( hours=startHour,  minutes=startMinute )
    endTime = dt.timedelta( hours=endHour,  minutes=endMinute )

    startDate = dt.datetime( year=now.year,  month=startMonth,  day=startDay )
    endDate = dt.datetime( year=now.year,  month=endMonth,  day=endDay )

    startDateTime = dt.datetime( year=now.year,  month=startMonth,  day=startDay ) +startTime
    endDateTime = dt.datetime( year=now.year,  month=endMonth,  day=endDay ) +endTime

    timeCalc = endDateTime -startDateTime
    result = timeCalc.total_seconds() 
    finalResult = float( result /3600.0 )

    if startDate != endDate:
        if finalResult >= 24:
            finalResult -= 16.5

    elif startDate == endDate and endHour > 12 or ( endHour == 11 and endMinute >= 30 ):
        finalResult = f'{finalResult -0.5}    w/ lunch'

    print( f'Final Result: {finalResult}\nDone.' )
    print( f'Start date: {startDateTime}' )
    print( f'End date: {endDateTime}\n' )

    window[ 'result' ].update( finalResult )
    window.refresh()

##  eof  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Yeah what I was trying to do was basically only count the hours between like 06:30 and 15:30. Otherwise disregard the hours. So if I was working on a job from 08:30 in the morning and I didn't finish until 10:00 the next day, I would bill my client for 9.5 hours (If my mental math is right.) but If I was working on a job starting from 07:00 and ends at 13:00 all it does is account for a 30 minute lunch break. I hope I'm making sense